# Automating the numbers of tags in Array of PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Each `tag` word has a number value at the end. Like this:

```
$values = array('tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4','tag5','tag6','tag7','tag8',...);
```

How can these numbers be generated automatically?

Comment: @u_mulder I tried with `foreach` & `for` but i don't think it's true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` is a simple and clear way to achive what you need. Another option is:

```
$values = array_map(function($v) { return 'tag' . $v; }, range(1,8));
```

Comment: Can the range be determined automatically? Is it possible?

Comment: What does it mean - automatically? Replace `8` with any variable with required value.